# Partial derivative to get rate of change *toward the origin*

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I’m trying to solve the following problem:

> Suppose the electric potential at $(x, y)$ is $\ln{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}.$ Find the rate of change of the potential at $(3, 4)$ toward the origin and also in a direction at a right angle to the direction toward the origin

**What I tried:** I took a random unit vector $<1,0>$ (a vector along the $x$ axis, going away from the origin) and multiplied it by $-1$, hoping to get a unit vector towards the origin.

Then I find the gradient vector of $f$, that is we get $\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}=\dfrac{x}{x^2+y^2}\;$ and $\;\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}=\dfrac{y}{x^2+y^2}$

Finally I use $D_{\,\vec{u}}\,F(3,4)=-1\left(\dfrac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right)+0\left(\dfrac{y}{{x^2+y^{2}}}\right)$

And find $\,\dfrac{-3}{25}.$
This is wrong as the answer is actually $\,\dfrac{1}{5}\,.\,$ What did I do wrong here?

Comment: The vector towards the origin, is from your point (3,4) towards the origin

Comment: I see, thank you for your comment. I answered my question below, But hank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

As @bananapeel22 advised, you can't just go from any point towards the origin, you have to get a rate of change coming from your point $P(3,4)$ towards $O(0,0)$.

The direction towards the origin $O$ from $P$ is represented by the vector $\;\vec{u}= O - P= (0,0)-(3,4)=(-3,-4)$.

You then take $\;\vec{u}=\dfrac{u}{||u||}\;$ to get a new unit vector from $(3,4)$ to $(0,0)$ and you now deal with $\;\vec{u}=<-\dfrac35,-\dfrac45>$.

From there on $\;\dfrac{-3}{5}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{3}{25}+\dfrac{-4}{5}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{4}{25}=-\dfrac15.$